# Anchors defined with `\hyperdef` are lost when the PDF is processed by `gs`

Tags: hyperref

We're abusing `gs` to "compress" a PDF and in this process the anchors in the PDF are lost.

Take for example the following `example.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdfa]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{Source a}
\hyperdef{cat1}{link1}{target1}
Foo \hyperref{example.pdf}{cat2}{link2}{to section 2} bar

\section{Source b}
\hyperdef{cat2}{link2}{target2}
Foo \hyperref{example.pdf}{cat1}{link1}{to section 1} bar
\end{document}
```

The anchors in the resulting `example.pdf` work fine, one is able to click the two links and the PDF viewer goes from one to the other:

```
$ pdflatex example.tex
```

When processing the PDF with `gs`, the links persist but the anchors are gone, clicking the two links does nothing:

```
$ gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPrinted=false -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTIGNS=/printer -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=/tmp/example.pdf example.pdf
```

Any way to preserve the anchors?

The questions I was able to find around here were about links disappearing. For this the recommendation was to use the `pdfa` option and the `-dPrinted=false` flag. These affect the "Annotations" (of type "Link") which get a "Print" flag and thus `gs` does not filter them out anymore. (I also tried to make the links *gone* by removing the option and the flag, but I was only able to do that with `-dNoView`. But I digress..)

Searching the hyperref repo for `hyperdef` returns only test files and a documentation file. https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Alatex3%2Fhyperref%20hyperdef&type=code

I tried to find the anchor elements in the PDF by browsing the structure of the PDF with https://flathub.org/apps/net.sourceforge.Pdfedit, but was not able to find anything.

Answer (score 2):

With `qpdf --qdf --object-streams=disable example.pdf example.txt` looking in the resulting file there is an object with `/Names` which seems to be relevant because it's missing from the processed PDF. See below.

Searching for "Names" in the ghostscript issue tracker reveals https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=695760 "Make more effort to preserve Names tree from input PDF", created about nine years ago, which seems to be exactly the issue.

As a workaround, one can use easily use [extractpdfmark](https://ctan.org/pkg/extractpdfmark), for example:

```
$ extractpdfmark example.pdf > pdfmark.ps
$ gs -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFDontUseFontObjectNum -sOutputFile=Final.pdf example.pdf pdfmark.ps
```

```
%% Original object ID: 32 0
7 0 obj
<<
  /Limits [
    (Doc-Start)
    (section.2)
  ]
  /Names [
    (Doc-Start)
    11 0 R
    (cat1.link1)
    12 0 R
    (cat2.link2)
    13 0 R
    (page.1)
    14 0 R
    (section.1)
    15 0 R
    (section.2)
    16 0 R
  ]
>>
endobj


%% Original object ID: 12 0
17 0 obj
<<
  /A <<
    /D (cat2.link2)
    /F (example.pdf)
    /S /GoToR
  >>
  /Border [
    0
    0
    1
  ]
  /C [
    0
    .5
    .5
  ]
  /F 4
  /H /I
  /Rect [
    186.349
    632.481
    238.764
    643.329
  ]
  /Subtype /Link
  /Type /Annot
>>
endobj

%% Original object ID: 13 0
18 0 obj
<<
  /A <<
    /D (cat1.link1)
    /F (example.pdf)
    /S /GoToR
  >>
  /Border [
    0
    0
    1
  ]
  /C [
    0
    .5
    .5
  ]
  /F 4
  /H /I
  /Rect [
    186.349
    577.714
    238.764
    588.562
  ]
  /Subtype /Link
  /Type /Annot
>>
endobj
```

Comment: you can produce uncompressed PDF directly by putting `\ExplSyntaxOn\sys_ensure_backend:\pdf_uncompress:\ExplSyntaxOff` at the begin of the tex file. But beside this: if ghostscript removes the name tree with the destinations there is not much one can do on the hyperref/LaTeX side.